# como hago el siguiente problema en codigo lenguaje c?

Tags: c

cargue dos vectores de 8 elementos cada uno y en un 3er vector la multiplicación .
Calcule promedio de ese vector ,genere una funcion que reciba el valor promedio y retorne el mismo dividido por 2.

Comment: Hola Lucas, muestranos cuál ha sido tu avance, sólo así te podremos ayudar. Lee el [tour] y [ask]

Answer (score 0):

Aqui en si esta el codigo solo pasalo a funciones que ocupas y ya esta

```js
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define tam 8

main(){
    int a [tam],b [tam],c [tam], i, j,m,r,total;
   
    system("cls");
    printf("\Multiplicación De Matrices\n");
   /*** Introduces Valores A Los Vectores ***/
            printf("Matriz 1\n");
             for(i=0;i<tam;i++){
                printf("Por favor el elemento %d \n ", i+1);
                scanf("%d",&a[i]);
                system("cls");
            }

            system("cls");
            printf("Vector 2\n");
            for(i=0;i<tam;i++){
                printf("Por favor el elemento %d \n ", j+1);
                scanf("%d",&b[i]);
                system("cls");
            }

            system("cls");
            /*** Aqui tienes la multilicacion en un tercer vector ***/
            for(i=0;i<tam;i++){
                    c[i] = a[i] * b[i];
            }
           /*** Aqui Tenemos El Promedio ***/
            for(i=0;i<tam;i++){
                 total = c[i] + total;
            }
            total=total/tam;
            /*** Aqui ya tienes divido entre dos ***/
            total=total/2;
            }
```

Comment: #include <stdio.h>
int v1[8],v2[8],vr[8] 
    float multiplicar(float);
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { 
    int i=0,num; 
    printf("carga del primer vector"); 
    for(i=0;i<8;i++) 
    { 
    printf("carga del vector numero"); 
    scanf("%d",&num); 
    v1[i]=num;
    }
    printf("carga segundo vector"); 
    for(i=0;i<8;i++) 
    { 
        printf("carga del vector numero"); 
        scanf("%d",&num); 
        v2[i]=num;                   ASI ESTA MAL INICIADO?

Comment: Te comento preguntas que no muestran código, en cambio solo preguntan cómo se hace no deben ser respondidas

Comment: si hice el codigo solo que no se como se sube.